# Javascript Selectors wont work in changing visible details

Tags: javascript, css-selectors

I have a code that generates the distance between two points and thus travel time and various prices, but the code isn't displaying the results in their correct spaces. Changing classes and ids didn't work nor did messing around with the ids:

```js
// Set up the map and geocoder objects
var map;
var geocoder;

// Get the user's current location and set it as the starting point
function getCurrentLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var latlng = {
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude
      };
      geocoder.geocode({
        'location': latlng
      }, function(results, status) {
        if (status === 'OK') {
          if (results[0]) {
            // Set the origin field in the mapping API
            document.getElementById('origin').value = results[0].formatted_address;
          } else {
            alert('No results found');
          }
        } else {
          alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
        }
      });
    }, function() {
      alert('Unable to retrieve your location');
    });
  } else {
    alert('Geolocation is not supported by this browser.');
  }
}

// Calculate the estimated route and cost for the trip


// Get the input fields for the origin and destination
const originInput = document.getElementById("origin-input");
const destinationInput = document.getElementById("destination-input");

// Create a new Google Maps Distance Matrix service
const distanceService = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();

// When the user selects a destination, calculate the distance and display it
destinationInput.addEventListener("change", function() {
  const origin = originInput.value;
  const destination = destinationInput.value;

  // Call the Distance Matrix API to calculate the distance
  distanceService.getDistanceMatrix({
    origins: [origin],
    destinations: [destination],
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
    unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
  }, function(response, status) {
    if (status === "OK") {

      if (response && response.rows && response.rows.length > 0 && response.rows[0].elements && response.rows[0].elements.length > 0 && response.rows[0].elements[0].distance) {
        const distance = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.value / 1000; // Convert to km
      } else {
        console.log('Error: Invalid API response');
      }

      // Get the distance and duration from the response
      const distance = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.value / 1000; // Convert to km
      //   const distance = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.value / 1609.34;
      const duration = response.rows[0].elements[0].duration.text;

      // Calculate the ride price based on the distance
      const pricePerKmExecutive = 20; // Pricing: $20 per kilometer for executive ride
      const pricePerKmClassic = 10; // Pricing: $10 per kilometer for classic ride
      const deliveryPrice = 15; // Flat delivery fee: $15

      const executiveRidePrice = distance * pricePerKmExecutive;
      const classicRidePrice = distance * pricePerKmClassic;

      // Format the ride prices and delivery price as currency strings
      const formattedExecutivePrice = executiveRidePrice.toLocaleString("en-US", {
        style: "currency",
        currency: "NGN"
      });
      const formattedClassicPrice = classicRidePrice.toLocaleString("en-US", {
        style: "currency",
        currency: "NGN"
      });
      const formattedDeliveryPrice = deliveryPrice.toLocaleString("en-US", {
        style: "currency",
        currency: "NGN"
      });

      // Display the distance, duration, and ride prices in the HTML
      const aboutSectionTitle1 = document.querySelector(".about-section-1 .about-section-title");
      aboutSectionTitle1.innerHTML = `Executive Ride: <strong>${formattedExecutivePrice}</strong> / ${distance.toFixed(2)} km / <span class="black-text">${duration}</span>`;

      const ridePriceElement1 = document.querySelector(".about-section-1 #ride-price");
      ridePriceElement1.innerHTML = `<strong>${formattedExecutivePrice}</strong>`;

      const distanceElement1 = document.querySelector(".about-section-1 #distance");
      distanceElement1.innerHTML = `${distance.toFixed(2)} km`;

      const durationElement1 = document.querySelector(".about-section-1 #duration");
      durationElement1.innerHTML = `${duration}`;



      const aboutSectionTitle2 = document.querySelector(".about-section-2 .about-section-title");
      aboutSectionTitle2.innerHTML = `Classic Ride: <strong>${formattedClassicPrice}</strong> / ${distance.toFixed(2)} km / <span class="black-text">${duration}</span>`;

      const ridePriceElement2 = document.querySelector(".about-section-2 #ride-price");
      ridePriceElement2.innerHTML = `<strong>${formattedClassicPrice}</strong>`;

      const distanceElement2 = document.querySelector(".about-section-2 #distance");
      distanceElement2.innerHTML = `${distance.toFixed(2)} km`;

      const durationElement2 = document.querySelector(".about-section-2 #duration");
      durationElement2.innerHTML = `${duration}`;



      const aboutSectionTitle3 = document.querySelector(".about-section-3 .about-section-title");
      aboutSectionTitle3.innerHTML = `Delivery Services: <strong>${formattedDeliveryPrice}</strong> / ${distance.toFixed(2)} km / <span class="black-text">${duration}</span>`;

      const ridePriceElement3 = document.querySelector(".about-section-3 #ride-price");
      ridePriceElement3.innerHTML = `<strong>${formattedClassicPrice}</strong>`;

      const distanceElement3 = document.querySelector(".about-section-3 #distance");
      distanceElement3.innerHTML = `${distance.toFixed(2)} km`;

      const durationElement3 = document.querySelector(".about-section-3 #duration");
      durationElement3.innerHTML = `${duration}`;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="about-section">

  <div id="executive-ride" class="about-section-1 hidden">
    <div class="about-section-title"> Executive Ride: <strong id="ride-price">₦NaN</strong> / <span id="distance"></span> km / <span class="black-text" id="duration"></span>
      <div id="total-price"></div>
      <div class="about-section-more">
        NOTE: This is an approximate estimate. Actual cost may vary according to the traffic.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="classic-ride" class="about-section-2 hidden">
    <div class="about-section-title">
      Classic Ride: <strong id="ride-price">₦NaN</strong> / <span id="distance"></span> km / <span class="black-text" id="duration"></span>
      <div id="total-price"></div>

      <div class="about-section-more">
        NOTE: This is an approximate estimate. Actual cost may vary according to the traffic.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div id="service-delivery" class="about-section-3 hidden">
    <div class="about-section-title">
      Service Delivery: <strong id="ride-price">₦NaN</strong> / <span id="distance"></span> km / <span class="black-text" id="duration"></span>
      <div id="total-price"></div>
      <div class="about-section-more">
        NOTE: This is an approximate estimate. Actual cost may vary according to the traffic.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That’s a **lot** of code. Please reduce it to a [mcve]

Comment: **isn't displaying the results in their correct spaces** -- where is it supposed to be displayed, and where is it showing instead?